# Need help using password_verify with prepared statements, password not verifying properly

Tags: php, sql, prepared-statement, password-hash

I hate to be the new guy asking can you fix this code, or at least tell me how, but I'm going on a month here trying to figure out why it doesn't work, and if its not obvious I've only been coding since February, so my knowledge is very limited, I have been studying several different courses, and have had success coding a similar script with md5 and in many other less secure ways, but I do not want to put a site online with those scripts.

My problem is I can sign up a user password,username,etc, is stored and hashed properly in database, but when i  try to log in as that user i cannot figure out why I'm not getting the password properly verified, I'm always directed to the pwd error line.

I'm working most the time during the week and have little time to tinker with this except on the weekends, but this is the fourth weekend now and id really love to get this fixed without having to rewrite the whole thing. I am really wanting to have something like this using prepared statements, i have compared each statement to the php manual and it looks valid to me, i have gone over it again & again & again, trying to find what is wrong, but everything i check seems like it should work. I'm lost.

Here are the files that should be required for someone to see whats going on. . .

signup script

```
<?php 
  require "header.php";
?>

  <main>
   <div class="wrapper-main">
     <section class="section-default">
       <h1>Signup</h1>
        <form class="form-signup" action="includes/signup.inc.php" method="POST">
          <input type="text" name="mailuid" placeholder="Username">
          <input type="email" name="mail" placeholder="E-mail">          
          <input type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="Password">
          <input type="password" name="pwd-repeat" placeholder="Repeat Password">
          <button type="submit" name="signup-submit">Signup</button>
        </form>
     </section>
   </div>
  </main>

<?php
   require "footer.php";
?>
```

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['signup-submit'])) {

 require  'dbh.inc.php';

 $username = $_POST['mailuid'];
 $email = $_POST['mail'];
 $password = $_POST['pwd'];
 $passwordRepeat = $_POST['pwd-repeat'];
  /// checks that user filled all feilds
 if (empty($username) || empty($email) || empty($password) || empty($passwordRepeat)) {
   header("Location: ../signup.php?error=emptyfeilds&uid=".$username."&mail=".$email);  //error msgs to user
   exit();
  }
else if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) && !preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/", $username)) {
  header("Location: ../signup.php?error=invalidmail&uid");
  exit();
}
else if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
 header("Location: ../signup.php?error=invalidmail&uid=".$username);
 exit();
}
else if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/",$username)) {
  header("Location: ..signup.php?error=imvalidui&mail=".$email);
  exit();
}
else if ($password !== $passwordRepeat) {
  header("Location: ../signup.php?error=passwordcheck&id=".$username."&mail=".$email);
  exit();
}
else {
  // checks for matching users in db
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE uidUsers=?";
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
    if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
      header("Location: ../signup.php?error=sqlerror");
      exit();
    }
    else {
      mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $username);
      mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
      mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
      $resultcheck = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt);
      if ($resultcheck > 0) {
        header("Location: ../signup.php?error=usertaken=".$username);
        exit();
      }
      else {

        $sql = "INSERT INTO users (uidUsers, emailUsers, pwdUsers) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
        $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
        if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt,$sql)) {
          header("Location: ../signup.php?error=sqlerror");
          exit();
       }
       else {
         $hashedPwd = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

         mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sss", $username,$email,$hashedPwd);
         mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
         header("Location: ../index.php?signup=success");
         exit();
       }

      }
    }

    }
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    mysqli_close($conn);

 }
 else {
   header("Location: ../signup.php");
   exit();
 }
```

Now the login script

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['login-submit'])) {

  require 'dbh.inc.php';

  $mailuid = $_POST['mailuid'];
  $password = $_POST['pwd'];

  if (empty($mailuid) || empty($password)) {
    header("Location: ../index.php?error=emptyfields");
    exit();
  }
  else {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE uidUsers=?;";
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
    if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
     header("Location: ../index.php?error=sqlerror");
     exit();
    }
    else {

      mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $mailuid);
      mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
      $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
      if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $pwdcheck = password_verify($password, $row['pwdUsers']);
        if ($pwdCheck == false) {
          header("Location: ../index.php?error=wrongpwd");
          exit();
        }
        else if ($pwdCheck == true) {
          session_start();
          $_SESSION['userId'] = $row['idUsers'];
          $_SESSION['userUid'] = $row['uidUsers'];

          header("Location: ../index.php?login=success");
          exit();
        }
        else {
          header("Location: ../index.php?error=wrongpwd");
          exit();
        }    
      }
      else {
         header("location: ../index.php?error=nouser");
         exit();
      }

    }
  }

}
 else {
   header("Location: ../index.php");
 exit();
}
```

Comment: Variable case issue? ... You set `password_verify` to `$pwdcheck`, but then compare to `$pwdCheck`?  If it is a typo, then this question can probably be deleted. Then you can refactor that area of the code to do a simple if/else check without needing else if.

Comment: What error are you receiving in ?error=

Comment: General tips: Welcome to SO, its a help site so you don't need a story as to why you're asking for help. Additional words of exasperation don't make your question easy to read and detract from the problem. Despite this you've provide a lot of detail and that's very much appreciated. The "pwd error line." could of been more tightly specified. Welcome to SO. We look forward to more of your questions.

Comment: Other code/sql tips: if you have `if { .. exit(); }` don't make an `else` clause it just makes the indenting and keeping track of it hard. When doing SQL selects, fetch only the rows you need and avoid '*', it can make it much more efficient on the SQL server side. Rather than checking a row before inserting, use unique/primary keys to ensure data is unique. Catch duplicate key exceptions as the way to ensure it isn't duplicated - this isn't subject to race conditions.

Comment: Forgot to add: ... if you know where the server error_log is located, there should be PHP notices about `undefined variable $pwdCheck` logged. Keep that log available while developing to help catch those sort of issues, or others, such as PHP Fatal errors. I typically have `tail -F /path/to/error_log` open in a separate terminal to check as I go.

Comment: please take a moment to read the php manual about what `ctype_alnum()` can do and how you can use it to validate your usernames without regex.

Answer (score 0):

You place the username in `uidUsers` and the email in `emailUsers` field, but then you read it with `"SELECT * FROM users WHERE uidUsers=?;"` and bind it to `$mailuid`.

I think it should be `"SELECT * FROM users WHERE emailUsers=?;"` instead.

Also make sure that the database field holding the password hash is of type `varchar(255)`, shorter fields can truncate the password hash.

Answer (score 0):

thanks Paul T. you were right on, the tip about the error log was a big help, I was not aware of that. As i said i have only just begun to learn all this a short time ago. The sad thing is I was taught in a tutorial to write the password_verify statement that way. I changed the part in question to . . .

```
  <?php

if (isset($_POST['login-submit'])) {

  require 'dbh.inc.php';

  $mailuid = $_POST['mailuid'];
  $password = $_POST['pwd'];

  if (empty($mailuid) || empty($password)) {
    header("Location: ../index.php?error=emptyfields");
    exit();
  }
  else {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE uidUsers=?";
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
    if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
     header("Location: ../index.php?error=sqlerror");
     exit();
    }
    else {

      mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $mailuid);
      mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
      $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
      if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
       if (password_verify($password, $row['pwdUsers'])) {
         session_start();
         $_SESSION['userId'] = $row['idUsers'];
         $_SESSION['userUid'] = $row['uidUsers'];

         header("Location: ../index.php?login=success");
         exit();
        }

        else {
          header("Location: ../index.php?error=wrongpwd");
          exit();
        }

      }
      else {
         header("location: ../index.php?error=nouser");
         exit();
      }

    }
  }

}
 else {
   header("Location: ../index.php");
 exit();
}
```

And now it all finally works as intended. Are there any outstanding security issues with any of this?

Comment: no security issues but the code must be [five times shorter](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli/password_hash)